# activity changing doesn't work. with sherlock activity

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

i just make two activity, and these are sherlockActivity.

i can press tab. but, doesn't change anything.

below is my source.

sorry. and appreciate.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sherlocktest;

imports;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ActionBar aBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal);

    /** TabBar */
    aBar = getSupportActionBar();
    aBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    aBar.setTitle("Darphin's bar");

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = aBar.newTab().setText("버튼1").setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = aBar.newTab().setText("버튼2").setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = aBar.newTab().setText("버튼3").setTabListener(this);

    aBar.addTab(tab1);
    aBar.addTab(tab2);
    aBar.addTab(tab3);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(0))) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal);
    }
    else if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(1))) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , ListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
//          setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    }
    else if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(2))) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
}
```

ListActivity.java

package com.example.sherlocktest;

```
imports

public class ListActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ActionBar aBar;
private ListView listView;
private List arrayList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    /** TabBar */
    aBar = getSupportActionBar();
    aBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    aBar.setTitle("Darphin's bar");

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = aBar.newTab().setText("버튼1").setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = aBar.newTab().setText("버튼2").setTabListener(this);
    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = aBar.newTab().setText("버튼3").setTabListener(this);

    aBar.addTab(tab1);
    aBar.addTab(tab2);
    aBar.addTab(tab3);

    /** ListView */
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    arrayList.add("first");

    listView = new ListView(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(0))) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(1))) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    }
    else if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(2))) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
}
```

activity_cal.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ListActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

sherlockTestManifest.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ListActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `appcompat-v7` library instead of `Sherlock`, it includes most of functinality.

```
if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(0))) {
      Toast.makeText(this,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal);
}
else if(tab.equals(aBar.getTabAt(1))
...
```

looks like this comparison doesn't work. Try assigning tags to your tabs

Also,

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayList.add("first");

listView = new ListView(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list, arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you're creating new ListView, why? And you don't even place it anywhere. You should find an existing ListView with `findViewById`.

Comment: first...
i can't write about "show me my second view!" at that plae
second. I replaced
listView = new ListView(this);
to
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
but still doesn't work..

Comment: have you replaced `if`s?